# Make your content disapear under the fixed transparent navbar while scrolling

Tags: html, css

In my body I have a `#wrapper`. I wanted to make the navigation bar which is fixed to the top, so inside the `#wrapper` I made new div `#navbar` that is transparent(70%). Next step was creating `#content-wrapper` inside `#wrapper` (a bit transparent too - 85%). And last one was `#footer` inside `#wrapper` that is fixed to the bottom of the site.

So the tree looks like that:

```
body ->
     #wrapper ->
              #navbar
              #content-wrapper
              #footer
```

Now, the CSS for #navbar:

```
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: rgba(154, 210, 78, 0.8);
z-index: 100;
```

Everything works fine here I guess - #navbar is fixed, 100% width and has the inline-menu inside, which is 900px wide.

Now the CSS for #content-wrapper:

```
width: 900px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
height: 5000px; //just an example
margin: 70px 0px 30px 0px;
```

and the last CSS for #footer:

```
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: "Calibri";
color: white;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #3a3a3a;
position: fixed;
left: 25px;
bottom: 15px;
```

- nothing special, just ordinary fixed footer I guess.

When I start scrolling down the page, the `#navbar` is overlapping the `#content-wrapper` and because the `#navbar` is a bit transparent, you can see the `#content-wrapper` through it. It not so bad at the end, but I want this website to be as perfect as possible, so I don't want the `#content-wrrapper` to be seen through it. I was looking for the answer for so long and I saw a lot of similar cases, but actually nothing worked for me. I was trying to implement the `position: relative or absolute` and `overflow: auto` onto the content and I was setting up the `top: 70px`, just to make sure content is below my `#navbar` - nothing. Tried some jQuery scripts, but they weren't so good, because they were just changing the opacity for the divs that are scrolled up. I can't think about any other solutions. Maybe my div's tree is bad, maybe I implemented the codes badly, but I was checking it with inspect-element function in browser, I was double-checking the code and nothing happened, I could still see the `#content-wrapper` underneath the `#navbar`. I'm not showing the HTML here. I'm sure everything is correct there. I'm looking for any solution - it can be some js script, php script, css code, etc. Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the transparency of from the `#navbar` I guess. So that you can’t see anything through it. And add a solid background to it like this:

`background: rgb(154, 210, 78);`

Comment: yeah, but I actually want it to be a little transparent :) I have some interesting photos and all the stuff like that which looks great if the navbar is a bit transparent